# How to clear microsoft ink picture control?

Tags: c#, microsoft.ink

Say I draw something and I have a button to clear , how do i clean/clear/reset the drawing on the control ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well so far as I found out say I have a button to clear I just need to

```
inkPicture1.InkEnabled = false;
inkPicture1.Ink = new Microsoft.Ink.Ink();
inkPicture1.InkEnabled = true;
inkPicture1.Invalidate();
```

so that the control gets instantiated with a new ink object.

Answer (score 3):

MSDN Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Get a refrence to the Ink Display object from the InckPicture's Ink property.

Then use the InkDisp.DeleteStrokes() method and pass InkDisp.Strokes property as Parameter.

**Example:**

```
            control.Enabled = false;
            control.Ink.DeleteStrokes();
            control.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Yes it does work.. Don't forget to disable and then re-enable the control