# Clear Microsoft ink

Tags: c#, microsoft-ink

I have a windows form application which let an user to write in a picture box using Microsoft ink.

I have used below code to use the ink.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ink = new InkCollector(pictureBox1);
        ink.Enabled = true;
        ink.AutoRedraw = true;
}
```

My problem is, I want to clear this ink when I click a clear button. Can anyone help me to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear microsoft ink picture control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447909/how-to-clear-microsoft-ink-picture-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the button click event, delete all the strokes.

```
protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
      ink.DeleteStrokes();
}
```

Go here for [more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.ink.ink_members%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: there is no method called DeleteStrokes(). I have added Microsoft.Ink namespace. Should I add another one?

Comment: According to the documentation there is, it's been a while since I used it so I can't remember off the top of my head. Sorry.